# PHP displaying SQL data and amount of times repeated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called **'event1'** containing info such as:

**| Name | Age | Nationality |**

I want to display, for instance, a nationality and how many times a certain nationality is repeated.

So for example: 
India - 5 
Australia - 10 
 
US - 10

The query I came up with was

```
SELECT nationality, COUNT(nationality) AS Total
FROM event1 GROUP BY nationality HAVING COUNT(nationality)>=1
```

I'm not sure if that is correct.

How can I display the above example using PHP?

Comment: You can use `COUNT(*)` in place of `COUNT(nationality)` and your query will be slightly faster. As far as rendering this resultset goes, it's just like rendering any resultset in PHP.

Comment: The SQL looks good so far. PHP-wise, what does your code look like so far? You can also disregard the "HAVING COUNT(nationality)>=1" part completely. All that does is display all rows that have at least 1 of the same nationality, which would be every single one of them. :)